# Chrome extension development: Call a method in popup from background_html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup

I have a popup named `mf_popup.html` and my background page is named `mf_background.html`.

As I start the browser my background page fires (as is my understanding, I am new to Chrome development), and I would like to call a function in my `mf_popup.html` page from my background page.

For example:

```
Start chrome

background page fires

background page calls some function in popup page (which initiates some stuff)
```

How do I do the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you place the needed code in both html-files in mf_javascript.js and includes the script in both with this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mf_javascript.js">
```

Comment: So simple!  It's sometimes so easy to miss the forest because of all the trees in the way :) Thanks for your help

Comment: What about message passing? Shouldn't that be a standard?

Answer (score 1):

**mf_popup.html**

```
//sendRequest([any type] request, [function] responseCallback)
chrome.extension.sendRequest({
    function: "foo", 
    params: [myParam1, myParam2],
    function(response) {
      alert("foo returns:"+response.result+");
    }
});
```

**mf_background.html**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request.function == "foo") 
            var bar = foo(request.params[0], request.params[1]);
        sendResponse({result: bar});
    }
);
```

You also could just use sendRequest("foo") if you don't want send any params and/or use an callback function.