# Run Chrome extension in the background

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently creating my first Chrome extension, so far so good.
It's just a little test where I run multiple timers.

But obviously all my timers reset when I open and close the extension.

So to keep all my timers running, I would have to same them somehow when I close the extension and make them run in the background page.

When I open the extension again, those timers should be send back to the open page.

How would you handle this?

I already have an array of all my timers, what would be the best option for me>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A background page runs at all times when the extension is enabled. You cannot see it, but it can modify other aspects of the extension, like setting the browser action badge.

For example, the following would set the icon badge to the number of unread items in a hypothetical service:

```
function getUnreadItems(callback) {
  $.ajax(..., function(data) {
     process(data);
     callback(data);
  });
}

function updateBadge() {
  getUnreadItems(function(data) {
     chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:data.unreadItems});
  });
}
```

Then, you can make a request and schedule it so the data is retrieved and processed regularly, you can also stop the request at any time.

```
var pollInterval = 1000 * 60; // 1 minute

function startRequest() {
  updateBadge();
  window.setTimeout(startRequest, pollInterval);
}

function stopRequest() {
  window.clearTimeout(timerId);
}
```

Now just load it...

```
onload='startRequest()'
```

---

Also, HTML5 offline storage is good for storing data and constantly update it...

```
var data = "blah";
localStorage.myTextData = data;
```

Comment: I see, so the background is actually always loaded? Not only when the user closes your extension?

At the moment I have my timers working perfectly, each time the remaining seconds are stored in the offline storage.

My problem is that when a user clicks a button, the timers start running, so in theory all my timers would have to run in the background?

Comment: Yes, also check if "*Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed*" is enabled in the *Options>Under the Hood*, if you never stop your timers! :)

Comment: Great, but one thing I dont get. How can my 'foreground' page communicate with the script running on the background? It seems that those 2 are separated.

Comment: If you setup *"background_page": "background.html"* in the "manifest.json" then you can easily communicate with foreground pages through Javascript.

Comment: That's what I did, but when I use "Inspect popup", I don't see any trace of the background.html or any script included in that page.

Comment: I can see the background in my 'active' views, but I don't seem to be able to acces them from my foreground page

Comment: Oh, I think I can figure it out with this: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html

Comment: The only thing I seem to have problems with is sending a request from a background page to the foreground page.http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html>

It doesn't seem to send any request from the background page

Comment: Then may find this helpful... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913580/chrome-extension-development-call-a-method-in-popup-from-background-html :)

Comment: They explain how to send a request from the popup to the background.
I'm trying to send one from the background to the popup: http://pastebin.com/j3kstVtm

Comment: Hey @woutr_be : Were you able to find out your solution? I am trying to send a request from popup to background, have background constantly run a timer and when it is time, send response to the popup. Seems the response is sent almost immediately.