# How to create notification after extension's popup closing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have simple extension with one popup page. After click on button on the page function in the background script executed which sends periodic request to the page and if it get 200 answer, it creates notification.
 
If I don't close the popup, everything is ok, but if I close the popup nothing happening.
What's wrong?

In the manifest regarding background scripts:

```
"background": {
"persistant": true,
"scripts": ["popup.js"]
},
```

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206982/run-chrome-extension-in-the-background

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].